# Make Carousel Container slider visible inside Inline Dialog modal

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a `Carousel Container` slider, and it's visible and works fine as a region on the page. But for some reason it is collapsing and is not visible inside an `Inline Dialog` modal window region. Why and how to fix it?

**EDIT 1:** The only viable solution I've came to for now is to create a page as modal and call it on click of a button with a `href`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only working solution for APEX 5.1 is to create a page with `Page Mode: Modal Dialog` and call it from another page, for example, on click of a button with `Redirect to Page` behavior.